# How to find textarea value after input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get the value of a textarea after input but not in same div with jQuery? I tried to do the `foreach` and `find` methods. I need to get the value and assign to JS object.

```
<div id="txtall">
<div class="subdiv">
    <input type = "text" value = "firstInput" class= "subinput">
</div>
<textarea class="textarea"  class="subTextarea"> firsttextareavalue </textarea>

<div class="subdiv">
    <input type = "text" value = "secondInput" class= "subinput">
</div>
<textarea class="textarea" class="subTextarea" /></textarea>

<div class="subdiv">
    <input type = "text" value = "thirdInput" class= "subinput">
</div>
<textarea class="textarea"  class="subTextarea" />second may be empty</textarea>

<div class="subdiv">
    <input type = "text" value = "forthInput" class= "subinput">
</div>
<textarea class="textarea"  class="subTextarea" />last text area value</textarea>
```

When I click a button I need to get value.

```
$('#txtall').find('.subinput').each(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    console.log($(".subtextarea",this).val());
});
```

The output needs to be:

> - firstInput
> - firsttextareavalue
> - secondInput
> - (this should be empty)
> - thirdInput
> - second may be empty
> - forthInput
> - last text area value

I also have to assign value to JS object.

```
function newObject(input,textarea)
{
 this.input = input;
 this.textarea = textarea;
}
var list = [];
$('#txtall').find('.subinput').each(function() {
  var obj_1 = new newObject();
  obj_1.input = this.value;
   obj_1.textarea = $(".subtextarea",this).val();
  list.push(obj_1);
});
```

By the way, I need to use `this` and I can't assign a different id or class to each input or textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textarea comes *after* the input, so it's the `next()` element from the parent `.subdiv`

```
$('#txtall').find('.subinput').each(function() {
    console.log( this.value );
    console.log( $(this).closest('.subdiv').next('.subtextarea').val() );
});
```

When you do `$(".subtextarea",this)` it's the same as `$(this).find(".subtextarea")`, which will only find descendants, and inputs don't have descendants.

Note that your HTML is **invalid**, you can only have the class attribute once, and you shouldn't be closing the textareas twice

There's also no reason to create instances here, and you can just map the elements

```js
var list = $('#txtall').find('.subinput').map(function() {
  return {
    input    : this.value, 
    textarea : $(this).closest('.subdiv').next('.subTextarea').val()
  }
}).get();

console.log(list)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="txtall">
  <div class="subdiv">
    <input type="text" value="firstInput" class="subinput">
  </div>
  <textarea class="textarea subTextarea"> firsttextareavalue </textarea>

  <div class="subdiv">
    <input type="text" value="secondInput" class="subinput">
  </div>
  <textarea class="textarea subTextarea"></textarea>

  <div class="subdiv">
    <input type="text" value="thirdInput" class="subinput">
  </div>
  <textarea class="textarea subTextarea">second may be empty</textarea>

  <div class="subdiv">
    <input type="text" value="forthInput" class="subinput">
  </div>
  <textarea class="textarea subTextarea">last text area value</textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: .Thank you for your explanation and map function.It seems more efficient way. Mustn't i use class attribute in another one ?

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that suggest you need to prototype anything or use instances. You can just push the values to an array, or map them to an array like above, without creating new instances every time

Comment: Actually i need to post mycontroller(mvc c# project) and my method is "public void save(int id,List<newObject>myList)" , that's why i did use instance. Can i map just like newObject instance?

Comment: Yes, you don't need instances for data you're just going to post

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code use **$(this).parent().next().val();** it will get the textarea next to the parent of input.

```
function newObject(input,textarea)
{
 this.input = input;
 this.textarea = textarea;
}
var list = [];
$('#txtall').find('.subinput').each(function() {

  var obj_1 = new newObject();
  obj_1.input = this.value;
   obj_1.textarea = $(this).parent().next().val();
  list.push(obj_1);
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/397cgxkq/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.next()` to get to the next element after the parent DIV.

```js
function newObject(input, textarea) {
  this.input = input;
  this.textarea = textarea;
}
$("#button").click(function() {
  var list = [];
  $('#txtall').find('.subinput').each(function() {
    var input = this.value;
    var textarea = $(this).closest(".subdiv").next(".subTextarea").val();
    var obj_1 = new newObject(input, textarea);
    list.push(obj_1);
  });
  console.log(list);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="txtall">
  <div class="subdiv">
    <input type="text" value="firstInput" class="subinput">
  </div>
  <textarea class="subTextarea"> firsttextareavalue </textarea>

  <div class="subdiv">
    <input type="text" value="secondInput" class="subinput">
  </div>
  <textarea class="subTextarea" /></textarea>

  <div class="subdiv">
    <input type="text" value="thirdInput" class="subinput">
  </div>
  <textarea class="subTextarea" />second may be empty</textarea>

  <div class="subdiv">
    <input type="text" value="forthInput" class="subinput">
  </div>
  <textarea \class="subTextarea" />last text area value</textarea>
</div>
<button id="button">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#txtall').find('.subinput').each(function() {
  console.log( this.value );
  console.log( $(this).closest('.subdiv').next('textarea').val() );
});
```